# Is it possible to change the Wordnet dictionary in TextBlob?

Tags: python, wordnet, textblob

I need to use the library TextBlob (PYTHON) for processing textual data, but by default it uses the WordNet dictionary, and I need to exchange it for a dictionary adapted to the Portuguese in the financial market domain for my research. It's possible? How?